# Repeated String - Challenge - Answers missing a few digits (C language)

Tags: c, algorithm

In short, we are given: "S" a string, and "N" (long type). We must print a single integer denoting the number of letter a's in the first "N" letters of the infinite string created by repeating "S" infinitely many times.

For example: In the case of: S = aba and N = 10

The solution is 7 because the first (N=10) letters of the infinite string are "abaabaabaa", and there are exactly 7 "a".

Here is the challenge link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem

My attempt only works for half of the test cases, and the first failed case is:

S = "epsxyyflvrrrxzvnoenvpegvuonodjoxfwdmcvwctmekpsnamchznsoxaklzjgrqruyzavshfbmuhdwwmpbkwcuomqhiyvuztwvq" - N = 549382313570

Here is my attempt:

```
long repeatedString(char* s, long n) {
    //Get the count of the string.
    long len = strlen(s);

    //Get the count of 'a' in the string
    long initial_count = 0;
    for(long i=0; i<len; i++)
        if(s[i] == 'a')
            initial_count++;
    
    //Get the reminder of the repeated strings, and then the count of 'a' in it.
    long reminder = n % len;
    long reminder_a = 0;
    for(long i=0; i<reminder; i++)
        if(s[i] == 'a')
            reminder_a++;

    //Return the total count.
    long total_count = ((initial_count * n) / len) + reminder_a;
    return total_count;
}
```

What am I missing? The answer seems very close. Thank you!

Comment: You have the input to your function. Create a [mcve] with that input hard-coded. Then use a debugger to step through your function statement by statement to see what happens and how the variables change. This should make it easier to find out when and where there might be a problem. Also try to simplify more complex expressions, storing immediate results in temporary variables. This way it's also much easier to see if some parts of the complex expression might be wrong.

Comment: Is `LONG_MAX` in hackerrank implementation greater than `549382313570` (approx 2^39)? Maybe try `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `((initial_count * n) / len)` is wrong because this cannot calculate the number of repetation of the string correctly.

It should be `(initial_count * (n / len))` so that it calculates `(number of "a" in one complete string) * (number of complete strings)`.

Comment: Can you please further elaborate?

Comment: @RandomBeginner Let's think about a case S = `aaaaaaaaab`, N = 19. In this case `initial_count` will be 9 and `remainder_a` will be 9.  `((initial_count * n) / len)` is  `(9 * 19) / 10 = 171 / 10 = 17` while `(initial_count * (n / len))` is `9 * (19 / 10) = 9 * 1 = 9`. The output will be `17 + 9 = 26` using the former expression and `9 + 9 = 18` using the latter one. In this case correct answer is 18.

Comment: @RandomBeginner In short words, using your expression, (some of) "a" in the remainder part may be counted twice because the number of string repetation is not truncated.